# leafletProxy clearShapes works once, subsequently data (dots) are added and not cleared

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

The shiny app below borrows from the superzip example. Four reactive parameters filter a data table and present the filtered zipcode level observations on a map. The app populates fine when run locally or deployed, it runs fine for the first parameter adjustment, however after that, the dots are no longer cleared and more data (dots) are added to the map. What am I doing wrong? Your guidance is much appreciated.

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
df = readRDS('data/hyops.rds')
products = as.list(unique(df$Product))

header<-dashboardHeader(title = "Title")

sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
# Year
selectInput("year", 
            label = "Choose a Year",
            choices = c("2014", "2015"),
            selected = "2014"),

# Product
selectInput("product", 
            label = "Choose a Product",
            choices = products,
            selected = products[[1]]),

# slider bar 
sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("CDI"), min = 50, 
            max = 150, value = 100),
# slider bar 
sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("BDI"), min = 50, 
            max = 150, value = 100)
)
)

body<-dashboardBody(
  navbarPage('Navigate',
  tabPanel("HyOps Map",
    div(class="outer",
      tags$head(
        # Include CSS
        includeCSS("styles.css"),
        includeScript("gomap.js")
      ),
      leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height="900px")
  )
)
))

dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body)
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(scales)
library(lattice)
library(dplyr)
source("helpers.R")
df = readRDS('data/hyops.rds')
products = as.list(unique(df$Product))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  sliderValue1 <- reactive({
    slide1 = as.numeric(input$slider1)
  })

  sliderValue2 <- reactive({
    slide2 = as.numeric(input$slider2)
  })

  yrInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$year,
           "2014" = 14,
           "2015" = 15)
  })

  prodInput <- reactive({
    as.character(input$product)
  })

  # Dataset Input Zip
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    hid = highops(df,sliderValue1(),sliderValue2(),yrInput())
    dat = hid$q1[hid$q1$Product==prodInput(),]
  })

  ## Interactive Map ###########################################

  # Create the map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles(
        urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>'
      ) %>%
      setView(lng = -100.85, lat = 37.45, zoom = 5
      ) 
  })

  # A reactive expression that returns the set of zips that are
  # in bounds right now
  zipsInBounds <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
      return(datasetInput()[FALSE,])
    bounds <- input$map_bounds
    latRng <- range(bounds$north, bounds$south)
    lngRng <- range(bounds$east, bounds$west)

    subset(datasetInput(),
           latitude >= latRng[1] & latitude <= latRng[2] &
             longitude >= lngRng[1] & longitude <= lngRng[2])
  })

  # This observer is responsible for maintaining the points on the map
  observe({
    bdiyr = bdiyr = paste0(c('bdi',as.character(yrInput())),collapse='') 
    leafletProxy("map", data = datasetInput()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircles(~longitude, ~latitude, radius=datasetInput()[[bdiyr]] / max(datasetInput()[[bdiyr]]) * 30000, layerId=~ZIPCODE,
                 stroke=FALSE, fillOpacity=0.4)
  })

})
```

Comment: Just for the record: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/shiny-discuss/1d9404b0-dc09-4402-8553-82b3957bc619%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer